# Check server console logs on azure app service

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a flask app trying to deploy on Azure App Service, but having a difficult time to debug the server error. I'd like to print out some information so as to see where the errors lies, just like how I would debug locally. I already tried the stream log, but it is printing out some html in the application log:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}
```

Which is not really what I am looking for. Also tried to set up the wsgi log in the application settings but it also doesn't show anything specific about what the error is.

So how should I set up the console output for the server? Where should I look for it?